# How to run external program inside frame enviroment using Launche in UWP, C#, xaml

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am writing an applikation for UWP written in XAML and C#.

My program will have the ability to open and run an external exe file using Launch. But when the new program starts i want to contain it inside my grid. My idea was to attach the launched program to a frame and then use navigate to get it in the right place but i have not succeded.

```
private void OpenProgramButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame ProgramFrame = new Frame();
    // here i would like to launch the program inside my new frame
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync("Program");
    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(ProgramFrame));
    // The MainFrame is created in the MainPage.xaml and is inside row 1, column 1 of a grid 

}
```

Comment: you can't do that, it is simply not allowed and possible for many reasons. One is e.g. that apps are usually running in their  own virtual environment for security reasons

Comment: Okey, Even if i have no interest in sending and reciving data between the applikations and just want to have it locked in the right place?. In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: Absolutely not, you could not render other app in the frame of current app. Because, they are running on  different process. You could not manage all processes in an application.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.